# Autodesk Forge Create Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, autodesk-forge, bucket

I have an app that upload a file to the Autodesk Forge server and show it in a viewer.. this works it but when I put this app into an Amazon Web Service, after de OAuth process when I try to upload the file, into the Create Bucket process I receive an error 401 "The token has expired or is invalid"

Why the app works on local but not in AWS?

Thanks

Comment: This could be many, many reasons ... hard to tell without a bit more code

Comment: and I would say you missed to enter your Forge Client ID & Secret when you deployed it. Can you double check?

Answer (score 0):

Because the token you received via OAuth is only valid for requests from the host specified in your forge process.

I solved this (for testing) by using [Serveo.net](https://serveo.net/), which forwards any requests to localhost of whoever requests it: call `"ssh -R <your subdomain name>:80:localhost:5000 serveo.net"` from your app and set `<your subdomain name>.serveo.net` as appURL in Forge. This way, serveo forwards any and all calls to your app, whether it runs on AWS, Heroku or your localhost.